# I want to use Open AL for the iPhone but it is to low level

Tags: iphone, openal, avfoundation

I want to change the pitch of my audio and I know that AV Foundation is not the place to look for that, but I don't want to learn Open AL because it is to low level, does anyone know what I would use as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this](http://variogram.com/latest/?p=24) link. Lately, I used csound API for creating MIDI sounds. 
But OpenAL is cross-platform audio manipulation library that is supported on the iPhone. Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742706/can-i-use-core-audio-effects-on-the-iphone/747623#747623) answer helps you. Take a look at this [FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2199.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dirac 2 for iPhone:
http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2-iphone/

If you want to implement this yourself, you could also consider using Core Audio and the RemoteIO audio unit.
Core Audio is also a low level API, but if you want to do DSP, you will have to use this kind of APIs sooner or later.

To get started with the RemoteIO unit:
http://atastypixel.com/blog/2008/11/04/using-remoteio-audio-unit/