# How would I add effects to AVAudioPlayback

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

I want to add effects to a sound using the `AVAudioPlayer` framework. Such effects as echo, pitch change, speed, etc. How would I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For effects, you have to use [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH3-SW1).
Unfortunately, it sounds like there aren't any canned effects included. Check out the related question: [Can I use Core Audio effects on the iPhone ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742706/can-i-use-core-audio-effects-on-the-iphone)