# Core Audio Filters

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use Core Audio effects on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742706/can-i-use-core-audio-effects-on-the-iphone)

you know where to begin to change the audio stream with different filters? as Voices2 app. I can store and play audio files, but I have no idea how to filter the sound. I know that I have to start from Core Audio, but I do not know exactly where to direct me. Do you know if there are tutorials, or mac app that help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/appleapplications/).

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) are the developer docs.

Comment: Then you need to clarify what it is you're looking for. The link above to the developer docs has a section on how to write an Audio Unit, which is a filter, which is what it sounded like you want. If that's not the case, please explain in more detail what you do want.

Comment: For example, I want to apply reverb to an audio file

Comment: Your best bet is probably to ask this question on Apple's Core Audio list. You can sign up [here](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo2/coreaudio-api). [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/AudioUnitDevelopmentFundamentals/AudioUnitDevelopmentFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH7-SW5) are the docs for how to load an audio unit in your program and apply it to audio. In general, you can create reverb by convolving your input signal with an impulse response kernel for the type of reverb you want.

Comment: Also, some examples are [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/AQuickTouroftheCoreAudioSDK/AQuickTouroftheCoreAudioSDK.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH11-SW1).